# Graph Clustering in Python, Hadoop, or other

Tags: python, graph, hadoop, cluster-analysis, graph-theory

Does anyone know of a package in python that can select a number of clusters in a very large undirected graph (100,000 nodes and a lot of edges) so as to minimize within cluster sum of squared distances or something similar? I am taking a look at MCL right now: http://micans.org/mcl/

Comment: 100k nodes isn't that big. Even with a complete graph the adjacency matrix is only going to need 4*100000^2 bytes = 37.252903 gigabytes (assuming the edge weights can be stored in single precision) which you can get on a single EC2 instance. Hadoop is overkill, have you tried simply doing this in networkx?

Comment: Ya could be over kill. I didn't see anything that would give me clusterings of nodes outside of cliques on Networkx. I would like to do spectral clustering if that was available, but it appears that there is only spectral bipartivity which returns a constant of some sort. After a second look, networkx can give me the eigenvalues of the laplacian so maybe I can just use that to perform spectral clustering.

Answer (score 1):

It looks either spectral clustering with mahout or this MCL algo are gonna work.